# How to get X and Y values in a fit function? R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get exact x values for a known y value and a y value for a known x value in a fit function.

The data are maximum discharge values of a river.

```
library(extRemes)
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)  

ggplot(K_Q_4_maxdis, aes(x=year, y=discharge)) +
    geom_line() + 
    xlab("Year")

fit1 <- fevd(K_Q_4_maxdis$discharge, type = "GEV", method= "MLE")
```

I tried this but I'm not sure how to go one. Below I tried to get the y value for a certain x value in the array.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 9))

shape = fit1$results$par[3]
location = fit1$results$par[1]
scale = fit1$results$par[2]
x=c(2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000)
exp(-(1 + shape*(x - location)/scale)^(-1/shape))

df1$X1=x
df1$X2 = exp(-(1 + shape*(x - location)/scale)^(-1/shape))
```

Would be great if someone could help me out.
Thank you already!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUjbP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkt9r.png)

P.S. This is my first post here so sorry if something is missing.

Comment: what is your function?

Comment: You want probabilities and quantiles of a GEV? If yes why code the functions yourself, there are packages on CRAN like [evd](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=evd) you can use.

Comment: The function is fitted automatically with fevd and in the help it says that the exp function is used as fevd. I'm trying to get a x and y value for given x or y value

Comment: Don't make us search for packages. Include needed `library` calls. Also, consider using an example from one of the help pages to create an object that can be worked on to illustrate you desired extraction strategy.